# How to make the pattern do not capture when the closing tag is invalid

Tags: regex

I have the following expression to validate a specific tag:

`<TAG(:([^:>\\s]*))?>`

This pattern should be valid for: `<TAG:abc>`, `<TAG:dfg>`, etc

How to make this expression be invalid in this case: `<TAG:hij>k>` (k> = invalid closing tag).

Comment: Which language are you running. If it's java then you need to escape the backslash one more time.

Comment: `<TAG(:([^:>\\s]*))?>(?=\s|$)` is correct! Thank you

Comment: `\\s` inside a character class would mean a literal \ and an literal `s` character. It wouldn't match a space character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a lookahead after to your regex to ensure that the tag must be followed by a space or end of the line anchor.

```
<TAG(:([^:>\\s]*))?>(?=\s|$)
```

OR

```
<TAG(:([^:>\s]*))?>(?=\s|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mM8xF8/3)

Comment: worked perfectly! RegEx is something that I need to study a little more... Thank you to solve a little bug in my [library](https://github.com/knuppe/SharpNL) =D